# JavaBeans validation in a desktop application

Tags: java, validation, javabeans

I'm looking for a non-trivial validation support for my desktop java application. 
In JavaEE6 there is a new [validation model](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html). Is there a way to use it in a desktop application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used them personally in a pure Java SE environment, but [JSR 303 Bean Validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) has a reference implementation in [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Also, the Spring Framework provides JSR 303 validation support:
[6.7 Spring 3 Validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation)

Comment: Good to know that 303 RI is Hibernate Validator. Have you reference to that?

Comment: I've tried to link spring validation, and actually is quite simple. Now I'm working on it, questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706350/spring-validation-in-a-desktop-application/9706487#9706487) arises on how to use it outside the container.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael, saying "Spring Framework provides JSR 303 validation support" you mean that Spring is a JSR 303 "client", it doesn't provide JSR 303 validation by itself.

Comment: does Java SE contains a simple validator?